# simple RESTful web services in java(JAX-RS) using jersey , throws HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, json, restful-url

When i am running my simple Java code for RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS), it throws 404 error. I have mapped it will in web.xml and have no compilation error. One suspecios message i am getting in my log is  " INFO: No provider classes found. ", please suggest me to eliminate this problem.

Console Log -:

```
May 31, 2014 10:23:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Reloading context [/rest]
May 31, 2014 10:23:27 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  stk5
May 31, 2014 10:23:27 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class stk5.ConversionService
May 31, 2014 10:23:27 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
May 31, 2014 10:23:27 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18 11/22/2013 01:21 AM'
```

my ConversionService.java file -:

```
package stk5;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("ConversionService")


public class ConversionService{
     @GET
     @Path("/InchToFeet/{i}")
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public String convertInchToFeet(@PathParam("i") int i) {

        int inch=i;
        double feet = 0;
        feet =(double) inch/12;

        return "<InchToFeetService>"
        + "<Inch>" + inch + "</Inch>"
          + "<Feet>" + feet + "</Feet>"
         + "</InchToFeetService>";
      }

      @Path("/FeetToInch/{f}")
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public String convertFeetToInch(@PathParam("f") int f) {
       int inch=0;
          int feet = f;
          inch = 12*feet;

          return "<FeetToInchService>"
            + "<Feet>" + feet + "</Feet>"
            + "<Inch>" + inch + "</Inch>"
            + "</FeetToInchService>";
      }
}
```

my Web.xml file -:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>restApp</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>stk5</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mentioning the URL pattern in `web.xml` I would recommend you to put this in your Service `@Path`.

You should so consider your context root, if you have not set it then by default it is your Deployment (war/ear/jar etc) name.

So modify your `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`. Now your URL should look something like this
`http://localhost:8080/[context root]/ConversionService/InchToFeet/2`

Comment: tried with http://localhost:8080/restApp/ConversionService/InchToFeet/2 but failed again. Context root include display name of .xml file?

Comment: sir, where to set context root

Comment: my console.  -> ay 31, 2014 1:07:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Reloading context [/rest]
May 31, 2014 1:07:53 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  stk5
May 31, 2014 1:07:54 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class stk5.ConversionService
May 31, 2014 1:07:54 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.

Comment: Sure I can help you out setting the context root, but which application server are you using for deploying your service?

Comment: Did you modify the URL pattern from `/rest/*` to `/*` ? Your console still shows `rest`

Comment: I am using myEclipse and have configured tomcat6, yes i have modified.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54831/discussion-between-user3675069-and-adheep).

Comment: Sir, how to add  and call client in my project

Answer (score 0):

What URL are you going to in order to test it?  The context is `/rest` and your path is `/InchToFeet/{i}`, so are you going to `/rest/InchToFeet/<num>`?

Edit: I also noticed you have a `@Path("ConversionService")` on the class.  That would make your URL `/restConversionService/InchToFeet/<num>`.  You might want to precede the ConversionService with a slash to make it `/rest/ConversionService/InchToFeet/<num>`.

Comment: yes, localhost:8080/restApp/rest/ConversionService/FeetToInch/2

Comment: Ok.  `/rest` is the context, not `/restApp`, so lose that part of it.  Also, you need the slash before the `ConversionService`.  See my edit above.

Comment: so a/c to you URL should be - http://localhost:8080/rest/ConversionService/InchToFeet/2                      but the restApp is display name under web.xml file.

Comment: If you check your console, you'll see `Registered web context: /XXX`. Can you tell what that is?

Comment: I could not found that. this is my console